# How to install sitecore Habitat's "visits detail panel" on other sitecore site

Tags: helix, habitat

I'm just wondering if it is possible to install/enable sitecore Habitat's visits detail panel onto our own (testing) website that is not sitecore helix compliance ?

Comment: Certainly. You are just going to have to copy a bunch of code into your project. It’s in the demo feature. https://github.com/Sitecore/Habitat/tree/master/src/Feature/Demo/code

Comment: Hi Chris,  thanks for your response. As I'm not very technical competent, is there a guide that I can follow ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not a "non technical" way of doing this, this code is non-supported by Sitecore and would need to be copied/integrated by a developer.

You may be able to achieve some of what you are looking for using [Explore Mode](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/content_authoring/explore_mode) when signed in to your authoring environment.